# TLS 1.1 won't disable on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, ssl, iis

I have a server with Windows Server 2008 R2.

The server has registry keys correctly setup to allow use of TLS 1.2 and prevent use of TLS 1.1 or earlier versions (and the machine has been restarted and has all windows updates applied)

e.g. For TLS 1.1 (and similar for earlier versions)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client 
DisabledByDefault == 1
Enabled = 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server 
DisabledByDefault == 1
Enabled = 0

e.g. For TLS 1.2
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client 
DisabledByDefault == 0
Enabled = 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server 
DisabledByDefault == 0
Enabled = 1

Also, not sure if they are needed but I have

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
DefaultSecureProtocols = 0x00000800

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
DefaultSecureProtocols = 0x00000800

A website running on the box targets .NET 4.7

The website has the following code in app start of Global.aspx

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

(I know that stating the TLS version is not forward compatible)

I can successfully connect to the website with TLS 1.2

I can't connect to the website using TLS 1.0 or earlier. So the registry settings to disable that seem to have worked.

However I can connect to the website using TLS 1.1 despite me having what I believe to be the correct registry information. I've verified this by

1. Changing firefox on the server to only use TLS 1.1 and checking that its definitely using that by visiting https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html
2. Changing firefox on my local machine to only use TLS 1.1 and checking that its definitely using that by visiting https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

I can also see what TLS versions the site supports with 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
(Its says yes against 1.2 and 1.1 and no against everything else)

We need to disable TLS 1.1 for a specific client (we know that server changes affect all websites). So what else do I need to do to disable TLS 1.1?

Comment: "I've verified this by changing firefox to only use TLS 1.1". On which machine did you launch Firefox and what was the URL? You need to bypass every possible network devices and just test on the Windows server itself, to eliminate all the men-in-the-middle. "We need to disable TLS 1.1 for a specific client" is also not likely to happen, as the registry key changes apply to all clients, not just one of them.

Comment: BTW, Microsoft's own article is ambiguous https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#tls-11 You probably should set DisabledByDefault to 0 and test again.